# Emberjs - how to render nested route template without parent route content?

Tags: ember.js, routes

## Summary

I want to continue to use nested routes but without displaying top level content when the nested route is accessed. I'm not sure this is possible ?

## Detail

Initially my requirement was to to display a list of, eg, foods and offer the user the option to add a food item `foods/add` . Using the `outlet` tag at the top of the list template allowed a form to add a food item to become visible at the top of the list, transitioning back to `food` after the add resulted in the list being displayed without the form.

## New Requirement

The requirement has now changed and it's necessary to show the form without the the contents of the list and after a succesful add show the list without any form.

## Question

I know I could abandon the sub-routes approach and create a route such as `food-add` but is there any other way of preserving the sub-route (and the corresponding file structure, which I like) but allow the the template for `foods/add` to be rendered without the list content ?

Answer (score 2):

Each route has an index template which is only visible when a child route is not present.

You could do something like this:

#### index.hbs

```
{{#each foods as |food|}}
  {{food}}
{{/each}}

<LinkTo @route="food.add">Add</LinkTo>
```

#### food/add.hbs

```
<form>
  ...
</form>

{{!-- submitting this form would add the new food to the list of foods
      and then also transition back to `food` --}}
```

Here is some more info on how the index route works

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-routes

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes